# Show modalpanel conditional validation JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, conditional-statements, facescontext

After at all, I´m sorry for my english.
I have a problem showing a modalPanel.
I would like show a modalPanel if the validation of the form was correct and doesn´t show it if the validation fail.

```
<h:form>
  <rich:calendar id="date" datePattern="dd-MM-yyyy" 
    value="#{Bean.startDate}" required="true"/>

  <a4j:commandButton value="Accept" action="#{Bean.Action}"
    onclick="if(#{empty facesContext.maximumSeverity}) #{rich:component('popUp')}.show();" />

</form>
```

The maximumSeverity doesn´t work here because when the page load at first time, maximumSeverity is empty.

Is possible call the validation of the lifecycle of JSF to know if the form is correct or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `onclick` runs **before** the action is invoked. You need `oncomplete` instead.

If you're using JSF 2.0, it's by the way better to use [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) instead as normal INFO messages also count in the severity.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Accept" action="#{Bean.Action}"
    oncomplete="if(#{not facesContext.validationFailed}) #{rich:component('popUp')}.show();" />
```